how pass shopping cart array to backend api using json
I developed an API to serve as the backend for a Point-of-Sale website.
The website passes JSON to the API endpoints.
On the website, after a user adds items to their shopping cart, they click "Check Out". The website calls the API endpoint CheckOut(). The website must pass JSON that has what I would call 2 nodes, 'purchase' and 'lineitems'. My web developer is telling me he does not know how to send the 'lineitems' part of the JSON. I believe my answer should be, "well, you need to learn how to add the shopping cart array to the JSON", but my web developer is pretty experienced so I am wondering if I am misunderstanding. My question: How do you add the lineitems array to the JSON that will be passed to the API endpoint CheckOut()? I am not a web developer so I guess I just need the big picture or what to tell my web developer to read/google. Here is the JSON that my endpoint expects:
{
  "purchase": {
    "citf": "LPSO",
    "citfuserid": "2314734",
    "citfsessiontoken": "A6BBB754BD9F4EB9",
    "ytotal_sale": 20.70,
    "ytotal_tax": 1.08
  },
  "lineitems": [
    {
      "cpl_dscs_id": "0142C45AFF0A4C89",
      "nqty": 8,
      "yunit_price": 1.35,
      "ntax_rate": 8.45
    },
    {
      "cpl_dscs_id": "034CA60B26FD4C8A",
      "nqty": 1,
      "yunit_price": 32.89,
      "ntax_rate": 8.45
    },
    {
      "cpl_dscs_id": "03605BACB1364791",
      "nqty": 5,
      "yunit_price": 3.32,
      "ntax_rate": 8.45
    },
    {
      "cpl_dscs_id": "037FB5C58F8849B2",
      "nqty": 3,
      "yunit_price": 6.04,
      "ntax_rate": 4
    },
    {
      "cpl_dscs_id": "0B81210989A649AC",
      "nqty": 1,
      "yunit_price": 4.03,
      "ntax_rate": 4
    }
  ]
}

Thanks,
John

What you have there is valid JSON (or a valid JavaScript object structure, depending on the context), so it's not really clear what the actual problem is.  Whatever AJAX tooling you use should be able to send this structure in a POST request.


The website must pass JSON that has what I would call 2 nodes, 'purchase' and 'lineitems'

In technical terms, what you call "2 nodes" are actually an object (purchase) and an array of objects (lineitems). So I would follow these steps:

Build the JSON object;
Pass the JSON object to the API.

For point 1), assuming you're using Javascript (you can use both Javascript and Typescript with React), I'd try the following:
// Assuming you have an array of line items
var lineItems = [
  {
    "cpl_dscs_id": "0142C45AFF0A4C89",
    "nqty": 8,
    "yunit_price": 1.35,
    "ntax_rate": 8.45
  },
  {
    "cpl_dscs_id": "034CA60B26FD4C8A",
    "nqty": 1,
    "yunit_price": 32.89,
    "ntax_rate": 8.45
  },
  // ...and more line items
];

// Construct the purchase object
var purchase = {
  "citf": "LPSO",
  "citfuserid": "2314734",
  "citfsessiontoken": "A6BBB754BD9F4EB9",
  "ytotal_sale": 20.70,
  "ytotal_tax": 1.08
};

// Combine purchase and line items into a single object
var data = {
  "purchase": purchase,
  "lineitems": lineItems
};

// Convert the data object to JSON string
var jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);

As for point 2), that really depends on how your codebase handles things. Assuming you're using ReactJS, which you probably are given the tag of this post, I could imagine a solution similar to the following, all included:
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const CheckoutComponent = () => {
  // State to hold line items and purchase data
  const [lineItems, setLineItems] = useState([
    // Your line items array here
  ]);
  const [purchase, setPurchase] = useState({
    citf: 'LPSO',
    citfuserid: '2314734',
    citfsessiontoken: 'A6BBB754BD9F4EB9',
    ytotal_sale: 20.70,
    ytotal_tax: 1.08,
  });

  // Function to handle checkout
  const handleCheckout = () => {
    // Combine line items and purchase into a single object
    const data = {
      purchase: purchase,
      lineitems: lineItems,
    };

    // Convert the data object to JSON string
    const jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);

    // Make API call to your endpoint
    fetch('your-api-endpoint-url', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: jsonData,
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        // Handle response from the server
        console.log(data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // Handle error
        console.error('Error:', error);
      });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {/* Your component JSX here */}
      <button onClick={handleCheckout}>Checkout</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CheckoutComponent;


Thank you David and Alessandro. Very helpful. We got it working. Also thanks for the tip on what to call pieces of the JSON. I am working with a web developer whose Chinese is probably better than my English :-) so it can be challenging.

@vfpjohn Glad to be of help!
